# How can you save a replayed mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How can you save a replayed mission? I have tried Google and I couldn't find it and I found this link.

I really want to  know how because during the last mission of the game

> (where you choose to kill Trevor or kill Michael or death wish) I chose to kill Trevor but now I want to get him back.

I replayed the third way mission three times and I couldn't save it, so I just want to know if you can save a replayed mission?

Answer (score 1):

**No you can't**. Re-playing a mission is like creating a "Temporary save" that will be disposed when you're done with it, after which you will be taken back to your normal game at the exact same point you were right before starting the replay.

If you really want to change this mission outcome, **you'll have to load another save before you're making this choice**, so you can choose something else.

PS: I edited your post to include a spoiler tag, feel free to do so anytime you're talking about the game plot or something similar ;)